# Copy org-babel Source Block

Tags: org-babel

I have this great piece of code to copy the contents of a code block:

```el
(defun copy-org-babel-source-block-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (kill-new (plist-get (cadr (org-element-at-point)) :value))
  )
```

How can I modify this to also include the actual block, with headers and all?

Answer (score 2):

You could inspect the `(org-element-at-point)` using `M-:`, you would find it has a :begin and :end property.

Then you can copy the full region as follows:

```lisp
(defun copy-org-babel-source-block-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((e (org-element-at-point))
         (beg (org-element-property :begin e))
         (end (org-element-property :end e))
         (text (string-trim-right (buffer-substring beg end))))
    (kill-new text)))
```

As the `:end` is not (always/ever) on the `#+END_SRC` line, we trim the trailing whitespace before adding to the kill-ring.

Comment: You might want to check that point is inside a source block before you act: `(when (eq (org-element-type element) 'src-block) ... )`